# Hibernate: Make a ManyToOne relationship work with unmatched key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a many-to-one relationship between two objects: SomeProjectType and Work Orders. In `SomeProjectType`, I have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

SomeProjectType has a "ProjectKey" as the @id for it.

And in `WorkOrder` I have:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "WorkOrderProjectKey")
private SomeProjectType project;
```

The issue I am having is that sometimes in WorkOrder, the "WorkOrderProjectKey" has a project key that doesn't exist in SomeProjectType (I am not sure why, but it is by design).

My question is: Is there a way to have Hibernate still return back rows even if some do not match? I have tried "nullable=true" and "optional=true" but it still won't work.

Comment: how you are selecting? HQL or get or ...?

Comment: I am selecting by HQL. Doing: `query.createQuery("FROM SomeProjectType WHERE projectKey = :projectKey");`

Answer (score 0):

try to this code because i have same problem then i will change code and work properly.

Primary Key Tables

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
private List<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

Foreign Key Table

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "WorkOrderProjectKey")
private SomeProjectType project;
```

Comment: Was there something to be different in the "then" part? Because it looks the same as I have above

Comment: So there is no difference on the Foreign Key, just the Primary? Let me give this a try, thanks!

Comment: When I try that, I get the following error: `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! Under the `@ManyToOne`, I put the following and it gets everything.

```
@NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )
```

Got this from the answer here:
[Hibernate chokes on missing rows when dealing with a legacy database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795126/hibernate-chokes-on-missing-rows-when-dealing-with-a-legacy-database)